# Weird behavior of a C++ program

Tags: c++

There is a weird behavior with a call back to a function. I want to compute the root of a function with the bisect method. The system to solve involves the integration of a function in which the upper limit is a function of another function, which is not a big deal. When I put the numerical value, the program ends well, but if I do the call back of the function, the terminal kills the process, and the program goes slower. By the way, those are one of my first code in c++.

The code block is the next;

```cpp
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct Ninj_Params{
   double p;
   double Q0;
   double gamma_m;
};


double c = 1;
double eV = 1.0;
double MeV = pow(10,6) * eV;
double me = 0.510998902 * MeV;
double e = 8.542 * pow(10,-2);
double fm = 1/197.3269602 * 1/MeV;
double cm = pow(10,13) * fm;
double Gauss = 5.788381749 *  pow(10,-15) *  MeV * 2 * me/e;
double meter = pow(10,2) * cm;
double sec = 299792458*meter;

// Function to find the root using the bisection method
double bisection(const std::function<double(double)> &func, double a, double b, double tolerance){
   if (func(a) * func(b) >= 0){
       printf("Bisection method cannot guarantee convergence in this interval.\n");
       return NAN; // Not a Number to indicate failure
   }

   double c = a;
   while ((b - a) >= tolerance) {
       // Find middle point
       c = (a + b) / 2;

       // Check if the root is found
       if (func(c) == 0.0)
           break;

       // Update the interval based on the sign of the function at the middle point
       if (func(c) * func(a) < 0)
           b = c;
       else
           a = c;
   }

   return c;
}


double beta(double Gamma){
   
   return sqrt(1. - pow(Gamma, -2.));
}

double R(double t, double Rs, double Gamma){
   
   return (Rs + beta(Gamma)*c*Gamma*t)*1./cm;
}


double B(double t, double Rs, double R0, double Gamma, double B0, double a){
   
   return B0*pow((R(t, Rs, Gamma)*cm)/R0, -a)*1./Gauss;
   
}


double Q(double gammae, void * args){
   
   Ninj_Params& params = *(Ninj_Params*)args;
   
   if(params.gamma_m <= gammae){
       return params.Q0*pow(gammae/params.gamma_m, -params.p)*sec;
   }else{
       return 0.0;
   }
}



double Ninj(double Q0, double p, double gamma_min, double gamma_max){
   
   struct Ninj_Params params = {
       .p = 2.5,
       .Q0 = Q0,
       .gamma_m = gamma_min,
   };
   
   gsl_integration_workspace * w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000);
   double result, error;
   gsl_function F;
   
   F.function = &Q;
   F.params   = &params;
   
   gsl_integration_qags (&F, gamma_min, gamma_max, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error);

   return result;
}


double Q0rate(double Ninj_Gest, double t, double Rs, double R0, double Gamma, double B0, double a){
   
   //double gamma_max = 1e8*pow(B(t, Rs, R0, Gamma, B0, a), -0.5);
   double gamma_max = 7.957e+06;
   printf("**** %.3e\n", gamma_max);
   double p = 2.5;
   
   auto root2solve = [Ninj_Gest, p, &gamma_max](double Q0) -> double{
       return Ninj_Gest - Ninj(Q0*1/sec, p, 1e5, gamma_max);
   };
   
   double root = bisection(root2solve, 1e40*1./sec, 1e53*1./sec, 1e-7);
   return root*sec;
}



void TEST_ROOT(double t, double Rs, double R0, double Gamma, double gamma_m, double B0, double a){
   
   double Nj = 1e47*1/sec;
   printf("%.5e\n",Q0rate(Nj, t, Rs, R0, Gamma, B0, a));
}


int main(){
   
   double t = 10*sec;
   double Rs = 1e14*cm;
   double R0 = 1e15*cm;
   double B0 = 0.3*1e2*Gauss;
   double Gamma = 300;
   double gamma_m = 1e5;
   double a = 1.0;
   TEST_ROOT(t, Rs, R0, Gamma, gamma_m, B0, a);
   
}
```

The line in question is the 105 (and the commented 106). When is set as:

```
double gamma_max = 1e8*pow(B(t, Rs, R0, Gamma, B0, a), -0.5);
```

the output is (with a slowly behaviour):

**** 7.957e+06
zsh: killed     ./Main

and if change to:

```
double gamma_max = 7.957e+06;
```

the program end well with the expected value of the root:

% ./Main
**** 7.957e+06
1.50212e+42

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please review [ask], in particular the part about writing good question titles. "Weird behavior" does narrow down the subject to runtime errors, but that still covers a lot. Not to mention that the behavior is (probably) not "weird" to someone who knows the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect to find exact values with `double` math... even the simple equation `3x=1` cannot be solved exactly with floating point math (the number 1/3 cannot be represented exactly by a `double`).

Your exit condition need to be based on some epsilon value.

IEEE754 double precision floating point numbers (what is normally the precision of C++ `double`) only have 53 bits of mantissa; so the epsilon value should be computed considering the magnitude of the values involved.

If say your function outputs values that can be "big" (e.g. 1E50) then an epsilon in the order of units wouldn't be enough (1E50+1 == 1E50).

Note also that floating point inaccuracies can create problems even in the intermediate computations, especially when big cancellations are performed (e.g. when you subtract two very big numbers that are close in value).

As Ted Lyngmo pointed out there's also a memory leak in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate so much memory that it most probably becomes slower and slower to find new memory. If you free it when done with it, it runs fine for me and ends with:

```
**** 7.957e+06
1.50212e+42
```

This addition is the only change I've made to your program:

```cpp
double Ninj(double Q0, double p, double gamma_min, double gamma_max) {
    struct Ninj_Params params = {
        .p = 2.5,
        .Q0 = Q0,
        .gamma_m = gamma_min,
    };

    gsl_integration_workspace* w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(1000);
    double result, error;
    gsl_function F;

    F.function = &Q;
    F.params = &params;

    gsl_integration_qags(&F, gamma_min, gamma_max, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result,
                         &error);

    gsl_integration_workspace_free(w);       // <- Add this

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I found that this kills the thread of the execution of the code. But at least for me, with the election of double gamma_max = 1e8*pow(B(t, Rs, R0, Gamma, B0, a), -0.5); still running but not end. Do you keep the election of gamma_max as this one? Did you add some truncation number?

Comment: @AntonioGalván I didn't change anything else in the program and I updated the answer to reflect that. I also have no idea what the program does. If my fix doesn't solve all problems in the program, it probably has multiple problems.

Comment: @AntonioGalván If I do change it to use `double gamma_max = 1e8 * pow(B(t, Rs, R0, Gamma, B0, a), -0.5);` it still exits with the same output.

Comment: Ted as you point, the program death because the multiple calls on the integral doesn't free the used memory. But the program doesn't finish because the tolerance was to small to the order of magnitude of gamma_max as point @6502. The solution is a combination  of setting the tolerance in other number to reach the exit clausule and free the memory used. Now I feel unconfortable to choose one answer that in fact was a combination on both answers.

Comment: @Pick 6502's then. It's more to the point I think. Strange though. I changed `if(func(c) == 0.0) break;` to `if(std::abs(func(c)) < 1.0) break;` (pretty big) but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Ted It works for me but increasing the tolerance for somethin like `double root = bisection(root2solve, 1e40*1./sec, 1e53*1./sec, 1e16);`. I wonder if @6502 doesn't have any inconvenient if I choose you solution as the best solution due the discussion.

Comment: @AntonioGalván The discussion isn't really part of the answer and I think future readers will benefit more from 6502's answer.